# Show a block of selection screen only to certain users

Tags: abap, dynpro, sap-selection-screens

I was trying to give an access to one block of selection screen that should only a few people see. For the rest of SAP users, it should be invisible but I've made some mistakes.

Declaration of the block that I want to hide:

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b3  WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-004.
  SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 2.
  SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 3(45) TEXT-ba5 USER-COMMAND x.
  SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 2.
  SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 3(45) TEXT-bb3 USER-COMMAND y.
  SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 2.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b3.
```

Fragment of code that should've done the job:

```
DATA: lt_authorized_users TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF sy-uname,
      ls_user             TYPE sy-uname.

 lt_authorized_users = VALUE #(  ( 'USER 1' )
                                 ( 'USER 2' ).

                              
  LOOP AT lt_authorized_users INTO ls_user.
  ENDLOOP.


AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-group1 = 'BLK'.
      IF sy-uname = ls_user.
        screen-active = 1.
      ELSE.
        screen-active = 0.
      ENDIF.
      MODIFY SCREEN.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track with `LOOP AT SCREEN` in `AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT`. But for `IF screen-group1 = 'BLK'` to work, you actually have to state which elements of the selection screen belong to the group "BLK". You do that with the addition `MODIF ID id` that is available for most selection screen elements:

```
SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 3(45) TEXT-ba5 USER-COMMAND x MODIF ID blk.
```

And then there is another problem in your code that isn't really a technical problem but really, really bad practice: Building your own authorization system! SAP already has an authorization system. It is built around roles defined in tcode `PFCG`, which contain authorizations for authorization objects defined in tcode `SU21` and get assigned to users with tcode `SU01`. You can check if a user is authorized to do something with the ABAP instruction [`AUTHORITY-CHECK`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_757_index_htm/7.57/en-us/abapauthority-check.htm). Whenever you deal with user authorizations, you should be building on this system. Homebrewed authorization systems are a nightmare for maintenance, administration, troubleshooting and compliance. Only build them when you have a **really** good reason why the SAP standard system doesn't work for you.

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b3  WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-004.
  SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 2.
  SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 3(45) TEXT-ba5 USER-COMMAND x MODIF ID blk.
  SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 2.
  SELECTION-SCREEN PUSHBUTTON 3(45) TEXT-bb3 USER-COMMAND y MODIF ID blk.
  SELECTION-SCREEN SKIP 2.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b3.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-group1 = 'BLK'.
      AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT Z_SEEBUTTONS
                      ID ACTVT = '03'. "Just an example
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        screen-active = 0.
        MODIFY SCREEN.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
```

You might wonder what's about the `BLOCK` and the `SKIP`. Don't they need a modifier ID, too? No, they don't. They can't have one. But they don't need one either, because when a block contains no visible elements, then the whole block disappears without taking up any space on the selection-screen.